# Finding an affine transformation that will map one set of three given points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ to another given set of points $P'_1, P'_2, P'_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, 3d

Suppose you given three points with known coordinates $P_1, P_2, P_3$, and also another set of three points $P'_1, P'_2, P'_3$.  Now does there always exist an affine transformation

$ f( r ) = A r + b $

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{ 3 \times 3}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^3 $, that will map $P_1$ to $P'_1$, $P_2$ to $P'_2$ and $P_3$ to $P'_3$ ?

**My attempt:**

The affine transformation can be written as

$ f(r) = A (r - P_1) + P'_1 $

For $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ , this automatically satisfies the first condition.

Now, we have to find $A$ such that

$ A( P_2 - P_1) + P'_1 = P'_2 $

$ A( P_3 - P_1) + P'_1 = P'_3 $

i.e.

$ A [ (P_2 - P_1) , (P_3 - P_1) ] = [ (P'_2 - P'1) , (P'_3 - P'_1) ] $

Let $G = [(P_2 - P_1) , (P_3 - P_1) ], H =  [ (P'_2 - P'1) , (P'_3 - P'_1) ] $, then

$G$ and $H$ are $3 \times 2$, and

$ A G = H $

Transposing,

$ G^T A^T = H^T $

Let $B = A^T = [b_1, b_2, b_3] $ then these unknown columns are solutions of three linear systems,

$ G^T b_1 = h_1 $

$ G^T b_2 = h_2 $

$G^T b_3 = h_3 $

Note that $G^T$ is $2 \times 3$ and the $h_i$ are $2 \times 1$ vectors.

A solution will exist for all these systems if $h_1, h_2, h_3$ belong to the column space of $G^T$, which is a mild condition, and is satisfied in most cases.

With this , we get

$ b_i = V_i + \lambda_i W_i $

where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} $.

Thus we have $3$ degrees of freedom in choosing the columns of $A^T$, i.e. the rows of $A$.

I would appreciate it if someone could go through the above analysis and verify that it is correct.

Thank you all.

Comment: This cannot work if the set $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ is collinear and the set $\{P'_1,P'_2,P'_3\}$ is not collinear.

Answer (score 1):

Extend $P_2-P_1,P_3-P_1$ to a basis $P_2-P_1,P_3-P_1,v$ then your choice of where the first two vectors is sent is forced, but you can send $v$ anywhere. Thus, in this basis, the third column of the matrix $A$ is arbitrary, leaving three degrees of freedom.